# Traversing through the conjugacy class representatives of the General Linear group.

Tags: group-theory, gap

Suppose I want to write an algorithm in `GL(3,5)`, where my main loop actually traverses through the conjugacy class representatives of the group. Here is an example:

```
G:=GL(3,5);

cl:=ConjugacyClasses(G);

for g in cl do

    %body of the loop which involves some operation on g;

od;
```

Now, the compiler is returning some error message. I think that the main problem is probably that the elements in `cl` are not being treated as elements of the group and hence it is unable to perform any sort of group operation on the elements of `cl`. I would like to know the remedy for this.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elemengs of `cl` are classes, not representatives. If you use

```
reps:=List(cl,Representative);
```

and then iterate

```
for g in reps
```

you will get the desired behavior.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: G:=GL(3,5);
K:=[];
cl:=ConjugacyClasses(G);
reps:=List(cl,Representative);
for g in reps do
Add(K,List(ConjugacyClass(G,g)));
od;
S:=Set(K);   Can you please tell me that what is going wrong in this now! The program is self-explanatory. The answer should be the number of elements in $GL(3,5)$. but, it is returning the number of conjugacy classes of $GL(3,5)$.

Comment: I mean the cardinality of $S$ should be the number of elements of $GL(3,5)$, but it is giving the number of conjugacy class as output!

Comment: @Riju - your code would cause a lot of overhead - you already have `cl` with conjugacy classes, why calculate `ConjugacyClass(G,g)` for each representative? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Riju - instead of writing a loop, try to do the fist iteration manually and see what kind of object is `List(ConjugacyClass(G,g))` and what is `K` after `Add`. Then you will see why the number of conjugacy class is the correct output of your code.

Comment: No, see I am just trying to understand how does the command ConjugacyClass(G,g) work. It is just a trial program that I have written to cross check. My first loop traverses over the conjugacy class representatives of $G$. Now, in another list I again add all the elements of each conjuacy class of $G$, which means that I get back the elements of the  group $G$ in the list $K$. The last line is just to make $K$ a set. The logic says that there will anyway be no duplication in $K$.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov ok I will try that!

Comment: @Riju I got it - good debugging approach! I think it will work i you will replace `Add` by `Append` - type in GAP `?Add` and `?Append` to see the docs.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much! Append works as it adds one list to another list, which is exactly what I want! Thank you!